# Apposition: two actions at the same time

Tags: appositives

If I was moving quickly and I was moving in the park at the same time, is ‘moving quickly is moving in the park’ a true sentence? I’m confused because I’ve only dealt with object (tangible) apposition.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community How can I get more clear on it?

Comment: It's a bit strange to say 'moving in the park' anyway... But if you really have to use it, what is wrong with 'moving quickly in the park'? Why do you need the verb 'to be'? No connection with appositions here, so your question is rather confused...

Comment: The main reason *moving quickly is moving in the park* isn't a "true sentence" is ***because it has no subject***. But even if we include a subject, it still needs some kind of conjunction between the two verb clauses: ***He is** moving quickly **and [he]** is moving in the park* is syntactically valid, but it's still completely unidiomatic because it repeats itself too much. More naturally, ***He is moving quickly in the park*** or similar is all the text you need to convey the intended meaning.

Comment: If we take _moving quickly_ as the subject, then it **is** a sentence, though not perhaps a very meaningful one.

Comment: There is no apposition there at all. Simple apposition: **My dog, a friendly enough beast**, was lying on the porch as evening drew on.